# Windows Server 2008 ask to change admin password and scheduled tasks stop working

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task

Every time Windows Server 2008 R2 asks me to change the admin password all the backup related scheduled task stop working, is there any way to avoid this? Backup is a serious thing an have to work forever. We have 3 server machines in a company.local domain each one with its scheduled windows server backup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally, you shouldn't be running scheduled tasks using the built in administrator accounts

My advice would be to create a service account and use that for your scheduled tasks. A service account is just a normal AD user, but usually has:

1) A VERY strong password (The kind you can't remember)

2) A meaningful name (E.g. svc_backup)

3) Password set to **never** expire

4) Configured so 'user' can't change password

The bottom two are just configured in the users AD properties.

You then give this account the relevant rights and privileges- ideally without making it a Domain Administrator.

Comment: Dan, I get the following error: `This task requires that the user account specified has Log on as batch job rights`, btw the user is Member Of Backup operators group that has this right. On the DC machine everything went fine but on the other server machine I get the error above. Do you know why?

Answer (score 4):

Create a new account for the schedules tasks to run as, give it a long, complicated password (potentially that you throw away the details of once you have configured things) and set it to not expire the password. Give this account only enough rights to do your backup.

Use this account for your scheduled tasks. Ensure that knowledge of this accounts password is limited and consider changing it if you are concerned about its integrity at any point.